# Update state of a screen struct from SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm coming from react-native and a beginner at Swift and SwiftUI and I was curious how to perform an action and update state on a specific screen when the app comes back into the foreground. I want to check the status of the notifications("allowed, "denied" etc.) and update the UI.

This is some example code - Here is the view I want to update:

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var isNotificationsEnabled : Bool

    var body : some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.isNotificationsEnabled) {
            Text("Notifications")
        }
    }

}
```

So far what I've been reading is that you need to do edit the `func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)` inside `SceneDelegate.swift` but how on earth do I update the state of my `Test` struct from there? I'm thinking we need some kind of global state but that's just a guess.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simplest approach

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var isNotificationsEnabled : Bool

    private let foregroundPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification)

    var body : some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$isNotificationsEnabled) {
            Text("Notifications")
        }
        .onReceive(foregroundPublisher) { notification in
            // do anything needed here
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if your application can have multiple scenes and you need to differentiate them somehow then more complicated variant of this approach will be needed to differentiate which scene generates this notification.