# @State vars in SceneDelegate don't update bound views

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, when I define an `@State` var in a `SceneDelegate`, then pass a corresponding binding to the contained ContentView, that view never updates even though the `@State` var is changed.

If the `@State` var is instead defined in `ContentView` and I pass a binding into a subview, that subview updates just fine when the var is changed.

Why doesn't `SceneDelegate` work with `@State`?  Is it because it doesn't use the same body mechanism?  Is something about `@State` initialized only later and any bindings generated when SceneDelegate's `scene(scene:, willConnectTo:, options:)` is called are invalid?

Note this seems unrelated to [Update state of a screen struct from SceneDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183545/update-state-of-a-screen-struct-from-scenedelegate), which doesn't place the var in the Scene Delegate.

Here is sample code for a view that does not update when a timer fires:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var s : String
    var body: some View {
        Text(s)
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    @State var show : String = "Initial value"
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        // Pass binding to our @State var to the enclosed content view
        let contentView = ContentView(s:$show)
    
        // Set a timer to change the @State var later
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { _ in
            // Explicitly run on the main queue, to rule
            // out the possibility of a queue problem
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.show = "After timer"
            }
        }

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@State` is designed to work only inside View, so you need to rethink the approach.